# Who was the Broker brokering for?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, Peter Quill attempts to sell the Orb of Morag to The Broker on Xandar.  This deal falls through when Peter reveals that Ronan's after the Orb.  The Broker then refuses to buy the Orb.  We later see both The Collector and Thanos are after the Orb, but it doesn't seem like the Broker is working for either of them.  The Broker refused to reveal who he was buying the Orb for, but it implies some 3rd person is seeking the Orb.

Who was the Broker buying the Orb for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**I thought it was the Collector.**

Two reasons why:

- The jump cut between Yondu pressing his dart to the Broker’s throat, trying to find out who his buyer was, and then straight to the Collector in Knowhere. We see the Broker is still alive when the action returns to Xandar, so he must have given a satisfactory answer.

  It could be misdirection, but that’s how I read that scene.
- Just after Quill and Gamora see the Necrocraft arriving, they also see Yondu showing up for Quill. This is *before* Quill has sent Yondu his coordinates from outside Knowhere, which again suggests that Yondu knows the Collector was behind the Broker. Otherwise, why would he come here?

From a practical perspective, it makes sense for the Collector to have multiple people trying to get the Orb for him. If he only pays out upon receipt, then it increases the chance of a successful acquisition without much increase in cost.

Comment: Possibly, but I thought maybe it was Thanos hedging his bets. He didn't trust Ronan further than he could throw him. Although, actually, I guess he could throw Ronan pretty far.

Comment: That's some solid logic, seems sound to me.